# I want to store list value in a variable and then have to write it into a file

Tags: python, file, list, variables

```
value,rows = DB.DB_sel('localhost','root','ndoitadmin','Example','select * from UC1_voip_gateway')
```

Here i am getting the values from database in list format

```
for j in range(0,rows):
     for i in range(0,21):
        # print value[j][i]
```

Here i have to print the value of the list in a sentence format so that i can pass the variable Name to write.file function to write it into a file

```
           Name = ''' '+value[0][1]+' 
                   list 2 = '+value[0][2]+'

                   .....etc ....'''

write_file.write_file(Name , Filename)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to serialise the data and spit it out to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Describing a little better what you want to do would help, but here's my answer regarding what I could understand:

```
outfile = open(file.txt, 'w') # Opens the output file

for j in range(0, rows):
    for i in range(0, 21) # I suppose this is the way how you obtain your "value"
        outfile.write("Value1 is: %s\nValue2 is: %s" % (value[0], value[1])
```

The output of the line `outfile.write("Value1 is: %s\nValue2 is: %s" % (value[0], value[1])` is:

```
Value1 is: x
Value2 is: y
```

And the for loop does it for every value in your database.